# Functions to manipulate IPv4 addresses in C#?

Tags: c#, string, network-programming, ipv4

Given a IPv4 address in the form of a string (ex. "10.171.24.69") and a netmask (ex. "255.255.255.128" or "25" for number of bits in network part) I need to compute the broadcast address, which may be by either zeroing or one-ing the bits in the host part (depending on the IPUseZeroBroadcast property which I can query via WMI).

I'm examining the System.Net.IPAddress class but it looks insufficient to the task. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any built in, functions, but you could calculate it yourself easily enough

```
static IPAddress ComputeBroadcastIP(IPAddress ip, IPAddress netmask)
{
    byte[] ipBytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
    byte[] maskBytes = netmask.GetAddressBytes();
    byte[] broadcastBytes = new byte[ipBytes.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < broadcastBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        broadcastBytes[i] = (byte)(ipBytes[i] | ~maskBytes[i]);
    }

    return new IPAddress(broadcastBytes);
}
```

You could also do

```
IPAddress broadcast = new IPAddress((ip.Address | (~mask.Address)) & 0xffffffff);
```

but the `.Address` property is deprecated.

Note that to convert a string like "1.2.3.4" to an `IPAddress`, you can call `IPAddress.Parse`, e.g.

```
IPAddress foo = IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4");
```